# Will a DDR2 Memory Card Slot SATA to M.2 NGFF SSD B-Key Adapter Board work on a Gigabyte MA790X-UD4P with BIOS F10C

Tags: ddr2, sdram, expansion-cards

I built a computer using a Gigabyte MA790X-UD4P motherboard.  I am using BIOS version F10C for the AMD Phenom II X6 1090T AM3 3.20 GHz CPU.  The motherboard is designed for DDR2 Max 16GB Dual Channel 1333(OC)/1066/800/667 MHz.

The memory compatibility chart shows 3 types of 4GB DDR2 memory that it is compatible with.

- Kingston KVR800D2N6/4G 4GB compatible
- Samsung M378T5263AZ3-CE6 4GB compatible
- Samsung M378T5263AZ3-CF7 4GB compatible - This is what I have

The system won't seem to work with all 4 sticks plugged in even though they pass the memory tests on multiple passes. I came across a DDR2 Memory Card Slot SATA to M.2 NGFF SSD B-Key Adapter Board and I'm wondering if it would work with my system to be able to use the full capacity of 16GB of the motherboard itself.

I also came across a plugin card for that DDR2 memory card adapter.  It's a TF (micro-SD) to B-key NGFF (M.2) adapter card Micro SD TF card reader card.  I'm checking to see if anyone has had experience with this type of setup, or even if it would work. I haven't found anything when just doing a general search for the info.

Comment: The DDR to SATA adaptors i can find looks to just be something that allows you to use the slot as somewhere in your case to attach a drive. They have connectors on top for you to plug in SATA power and data connectors and I doubt anything is electrically wired up to the DDR interface. The almost certainly won't allow you to use an SSD as "memory"

Comment: It can be used with a SSD or the M.2 B-key on the face of it.  I know that the board has the 16GB limit for RAM, so I was thinking of the micro SD card totaling up to the 16 GB.  Some of those DDR2 adaptor cards came with a SATA power cable.  It might require being powered by SATA while using the M.2.

Comment: What I'm saying is that those devices will not work as system memory. They will work as a SATA storage device via the SATA data connector on the edge of the card. The DDR side of the board is only to physically hold the card on your motherboard, not to allow you to use a 16GB memory card as 16 of RAM.